# SVN Commit issue is "not under version control"

Tags: xcode, svn

In my ongoing project i have delete image file from image assets. And add another image file with same name. So it display modification in "Contents.json" in mac application "Versions".

While try to commit from command line, it shows me error like...

```
svn: E200009: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E200009: '/Users/.../.../.../.../.../iOS]' is not under version control
```

can anyone help me to find out reason behind it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the actual error: `is not under version control`.

The error means that you've tried to commit a file that is not under version control. You should [`svn add`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html) it first. However, there is a chance that you made some unintentional changes in your working copy. You should run [`svn update`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html) and examine your local uncommitted modifications with [`svn status`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html).

Answer (score -2):

First You take a update. And Commit that new file.When committing choose merge option to commit the same file

Comment: I have taken update but still showing same error.

Comment: Did you choose merge option while committing ?. Otherwise the existing file will not remove and need to commit the your new image file in the same location with same name. If those option is not working you can delete that image and commit the new change. And again take update. After the new update. Then you only add and commit your new image with the same name in same location.

Comment: Thanks @Printce Varghese. But I have not merged anything from anywhere. This is the initial things. And i want to commit everything in the same svn revision.